# Themes Integration of Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, themes

I am web developer, now move to Android , today i purchase this one templates for my app.
http://themeforest.net/item/falldown-mobile-tablet-responsive-template/13111084?s_phrase&s_rank=3
now i want to integrate this one in Eclipse, 
how i integrate this one themes? 
there is css, javascript and html.
or i purchased wrong one templates? 
please anybody help.

Comment: "integrate in Eclipse" - please explain? Android is Java... http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have purchased the wrong thing. You purchased a web template for mobile websites.